# <video> HTML5 не отображается в safari

Tags: html, jquery, видео, safari

Вставила видео на сайт с ресурса dropbox. Включено автовоспроизведение, без звука. Во всех браузерах работает нормально, в safari ни в какую. Помогите найти решение

````
<div id="videoCover">
  <video style="object-fit: cover; background-size: cover; width: 56%; height: 59%; border-radius: 0px;" preload="auto" playsinline preload="yes" autoplay loop muted="muted">
    <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ddjrmuecyc2kwyd/frame%202.webm?dl=0" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
  let width = $(window).width();
  let height = $(window).height();
  $("#videoCover")
    .width(width)
    .height(height);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.autoplay').trigger("play");
});

$(window).resize(() => {
  let width = $(window).width();
  let height = $(window).height();
  $("#videoCover")
    .width(width)
    .height(height);
});
</script>

<style>```
````

Comment: поддержка ```webm``` -  https://caniuse.com/webm

Comment: @soledar10 получается не поддерживается ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете видео в формате **webm**, но когда подключаете его, то задаете формат mp4.

Вам необходимо заменить `type="video/mp4"` на `type="video/webm"`.

После этого видео воспроизводится, проверено на Safari 16.1

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это поправила, но в Сафари все равно не отображается
https://happyfoxstudios.com/

Может быть проблема в сервере, переложить файл с дропбокса, но куда ?

Comment: @Sofi выше отправили ссылку на caniuse, там можно посмотреть поддерживает ли ваш браузер формат webp. Если не поддерживает, то можете попробовать воспользоваться онлайн-конвертером видео (из webm, например, в mp4) и добавить его после первого тега <source>. Это будет фоллбек на случай, если нет поддержки webm.

`<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">`